# XSD - Fail Some, Pass Some

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to do something that may not be possible.

I have an XML document containing a list of records of the same type. Something like this:

```
<root>
  <record>I'm a shark.</record>
  <record>I'm a shark.</record>
  <record>Suck it.</record>
  <record>I'm a shark.</record>
</root>
```

First, I run it through an XSD to make sure the tags are correct. Then, I unmarshal it and do some programmatic validation on the actual values. I would like to fold this second step into the XSD via `<xs:pattern />` (match the values against the regex to test validity).

The problem is that I have the business rule that I should continue processing all the records listed in the XML document that are valid, and only fail the specific ones that don't. In my above example, I would want to fail the "Suck it." value and pass all the "I'm a shark." values onward to some processing step for actual use.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, in an XSD, if one part fails, the whole document is just "bad" and fails validation. So, in my above example, the "Suck it." value takes down the entire document. Is there some way around this? Am I just stuck with my second programmatic step? If I *can* only fail individual tags and not the entire document, is there some way to get at the "This tag failed for this reason." during the validation?

**Edit:** I ended up using a `SAXParser` with a `Schema` set on it, and handing it a custom class extending `DefaultHandler` which somewhat manually handles the XML.

I set up a private class `Node`, internal to my custom `DefaultHandler`, that is an incredibly simple Tree implementation. Each `Node` contains an opening tag, value, and closing tag, all stored as `String`s, plus relations to parent and children. Whenever I get a `SAXException` containing a message starting with "cvc-pattern-valid" or "cvc-type.3.1.3" (or whatever XML errors I want to capture), I remove the `Node` I'm in the middle of from the Tree I'm building (because it's broken) and just move on to the next. I can then output the entire document (minus culled tags) as a big XML `String` when I'm done parsing by calling `Node.depthFirstSearch()` on the root (which uses various `StringBuilder`s).

My problem now is that it feels like I am doing an inordinate amount of work just to treat the XML as XML. I have to re-add the "`<`", "`>`", and "`<\`" characters, because the methods in `DefaultHandler` only give me things like the stripped `qName`. And all this Tree-building and -traversing seems inefficient; like too much work. Surely there must be a simpler way?

Note: The reason I want to keep the XML as XML, is because this was my former workflow:

```
XSD -> XSLT -> Unmarshal to JAXB-Annotated Object
```

Now it's this:

```
SAXParser(XSD) -> XSLT -> Unmarshal to JAXB-Annotated Object
```

Maybe there's some magic way to do:

```
SAXParser(XSD, XSLT) -> Unmarshal to JAXB-Annotated Object
```

Or

```
SAXParser(XSD, XSLT, Unmarshal to JAXB-Annotated Object)
```

But I don't know what that would be.

**Edit:** Well, possible inefficiencies aside, extending `DefaultHandler`, overriding `DefaultHandler.error(SAXParseException exception)` was the correct answer, at least for me. So Petru gets the coveted green check mark.

Comment: What platform are you on? Java? .NET?

Comment: I don't know of any xsd validator that will do what you want. It's not at all what XSD was designed for. You might be to use XSLT effectively for this though. Just use a copy template that selectively copies.

Comment: @PetruGardea: Java. I'm using mostly JAXB, with a little Saxon for some special cases.

Comment: @StanleyDeBoer: I can't just skip the ones that aren't valid, I need to know specifically which ones failed so that I can generate notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB has the ability to set up a [custom error handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler.html) and thus allows you to override the default behaviour, which is to abandon ALL processing. Try it with your specific test cases, and seet how it might work.

As far as I know, all major validators have an event based approach to allow custom handling of validation errors, for the purpose of allowing processing to continue.

Worst case scenario might be to actually parse your XML with, for example, a SAX API - instead of JAXB directly - it may give you better control over handling errors; then whatever `record` node is successfully validated, unmarshalled into your JAVA class  (you end up with double parsing though).

Answer (score 0):

Let's distinguish between the conceptual and the practical levels.

Conceptually - XSD defines validity not only for the document as a whole (or, more specifically, for the document node at which validation starts) but also for each node in the subtree rooted at the node where validation starts.

So in the PSVI (post-schema-validation infoset) of your document, each of your 'record' elements is notionally marked with [validity=valid] or [validity=invalid] or [validity=notKnown].  As you observe, invalidity propagates upward, so that if the parent 'root' element has invalid children it will also normally be invalid.

The XSD spec says nothing at all about whether an application which discovers that its input is invalid should continue processing the input or abort; that's outside the scope of the XSD spec.  If you want to process the valid 'record' elements and do something else with the invalid ones, the XSD spec is designed to make it possible for the validator to give you the information you need in order to do that.

Practically - many users, and some implementors, have not seen the utility of the richer notion of validity defined by XSD, so many validators and code binding tools provide APIs that by default essentially reduce validity to a single Boolean property of the validation root, and in some this reduced notion of validity is the only one the tool actually supports.

So your validator's API may or may not give you access to validity information on the 'record' elements.  If it does, you just need to write your consuming code to interrogate the API and act accordingly.  If it doesn't, you need to tell your vendor that you need that information (or look for a different validator).  If you are using a data binding tool to generate your code, the same principles apply:  find out how to make your tool generate code that can soldier on in the presence of invalid input, and if the tool doesn't support that ask the vendor why not.

XSD does not attempt to define APIs or minimum-quality standards for validators, so the only way to persuade vendors to provide access to XSD's full native concept of validity is through market pressure.

XSD differs from other schema languages partly in defining validity not as a simple Boolean property of the document as a whole, but as a three-valued property (valid, invalid, notKnown) of every node in the portion of the document that was validated.  Usage scenarios like the one you describe were (contrary to the view offered by Stanley de Boer in a comment) a central motivation for that work.  So if you cannot do what you would like with your current XSD validator, the barrier lies in the implementation, and not in XSD itself.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon falls short of the idealized XSD processor that Michael Sperberg-McQueen describes, mainly because it is designed primarily for the needs of schema-aware XSLT and XQuery processing, which don't require all the flexibility built into the XSD spec. However, you can still get a long way, because you don't really need the full PSVI: what you need is the source document plus a list of errors [my term, not the one used in the XSD spec], linked together in some way. And you can get that easily enough - the details depend on whether you want a tree-based or event-based processing approach.

(The same is almost certainly true of other XSD processors as well, but Saxon is the one I know best).

If you select the processing options correctly, Saxon will always keep going after a validation error, though in some cases it will decide not to do any further validation on part of the document. For example, if a content model is supposed to contain (a,b,c,d) and the instance actually contains (a,x,b,c,d), then once the error is reported at x, no validation is carried out on the b,c, and d.